# RVM, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3, Passenger 3.0.2 (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I'm using RVM, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3, Passenger 3.0.2 configured for Nginx, 
I setup server configuration correctly. Another app working so far.

But for the new app, when booting server

http://myapp.local (its configured with hosts to point server bind on Nginx conf)
It returns (Bundler::GemNotFound) error. How to get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the stack trace of the error so we can get some more insight into it.

Comment: This is the backtrace from Passenger http://shorttext.com/w485coz56bs

Comment: it says "Could not find activemerchant-1.10.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)" but it cannot find any gem. Not activemerchant related. (Tested with re-configure Gemfile)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Believe it or not this is a very common problem most Rails Developers will come across. Have a look at this post which details the fix I think you are looking for. Best of luck. http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/21-rvm-and-passenger-setup-for-rails-2-and-rails-3-apps

Comment: It works. Solution also mentioned here too
http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger

Comment: Also RVM's .rvmrc file must be on root path.

Comment: Great stuff, Good Luck Harry.

Answer (score 0):

For a clearer and up to date solution, check out the official docs page on [using RVM rubies with Passenger](https://rvm.io/integration/passenger/).

For the gist of it, add

```
if ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'] && ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'].include?('rvm')
  begin
    gems_path = ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'].split(/@/)[0].sub(/rubies/,'gems')
    ENV['GEM_PATH'] = "#{gems_path}:#{gems_path}@global"
    require 'rvm'
    RVM.use_from_path! File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  rescue LoadError
    raise "RVM gem is currently unavailable."
  end
end

# If you're not using Bundler at all, remove lines bellow
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = File.expand_path('../Gemfile', File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'bundler/setup'
```

to your `<rails-app-path>/config/setup_load_paths.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

For rvm based apps and Passenger, you may refer to these docs:

https://rvm.io/integration/passenger
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRuby

My particular problem was that I didn't have the passenger gem installed in the current gemset:

```
$ gem list --local |grep passenger # returns nothing
```

To install the plugin and the Apache module, I've executed the following sequence of commands:

```
$ gem install passenger # for a specific version use the '--version' flag
$ gem list --local |grep passenger
passenger (4.0.18)
$ passenger-install-apache2-module
```

After the installation the script printed instructions how to set the PassengerDefaultRuby variable in Apache's config. Voilà! - no extra scripts and LOAD_PATH manipulation ;)

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why, but I installed the missing Gem in Global Gemset and it works!

Comment: Because you installed in the global gem sets. Global... get it?