# Bundler is ghost-bundling - it uses the gem but passenger returns a GemNotFoundError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm using Rails 2.3.11 and Bundler 1.0.10.

Passenger returns the error

```
Could not find addressable-2.2.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I installed manually addressable 2.2.4 and I bundled it with `gem 'addressable', '2.2.4'` did a `bundle install` and bundler says `Using addressable (2.2.4)`.

Still there is the error of above.

I'm using Passenger as an Apache2 module. I'm using RVM with Ruby 1.9.2. Passenger runs with 1.8.7. Even switching Ruby to 1.8.7 using RVM doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: are passenger using your "system" ruby ? are you using rvm or have multiple ruby version installed? are you using passenger stand alone or apache module? if apache posts the relative configuration rows (in apache2.conf)  and the result of 'which ruby' for have more help! have a nice day

Comment: well , be sure that passenger is using the same ruby of your default rvm console . have a look at your apache2 configuration

Comment: it is now using the same version, but that makes no difference actually... same error

Comment: possible duplicate of [RVM, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3, Passenger 3.0.2 (Bundler::GemNotFound)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798645/rvm-ruby-1-9-2-rails-3-passenger-3-0-2-bundlergemnotfound)

Answer (score 2):

Along with what Zachary said, that is making sure you have the right gemset selected, be sure to run

`bundle install`

in the directory of the project.  In my case for a Padrino project, once i ran bundle, it worked fine (with that gemset selected).

Comment: I already tried that, bundle update as well... makes no difference

Answer (score 1):

If you're using RVM there's a good chance your gemset for your project is not synched up.

Try doing

```
rvm gemset list
```

If you created a ruby for this project and a gemset for it, it will be listed there. Do

```
rvm gemset use nameOfGemsetForYourProject
```

RVM is a great tool, but it can muddy the waters and cause some confusion with making sure you're installing a gem under the correct namespace.

To check what gems are installed for a gemset, after you have done a 'use' on it, just type "gem list"

Comment: btw gem list shows that addressable-2.2.4 is installed and bundler says it'd be using it

Comment: the only imaginable cause for the problem to me is, a messed up bundler installation... i just installed it with gem install bundler and it always worked fine since the point where I implemented OmniAuth, here on my local working machine bundles the addressable gem, which OmniAuth depends on, automatically; on my server you get the error I listed above.

Comment: How many gemsets did rvm gemset list show? gem list only lists gems installed for the current gemset. If you're using rvm, bundle install will install gems for the gemset attached to your project.

Comment: i have a gemset teamforger and a gemset global

Comment: But I would like to get it running without using gemsets... just the good old way with standard bundles

Comment: The more I work on my new rails project, the more i hate bundler.  It took a difficult but solveable problem and has replaced it with something that breaks like 70% of the time in random and frustrating ways.  (I'm having the same problem too).  Something to do with rvm installed as root and bundler installing to the web-server-user's directory but then sometimes not finding them or smth.

Comment: Restarting unicorn with bundle exec unicorn_rails worked for now.